# Coefficients of recursive functional

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider the functional$$P:(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1})\to (\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1})$$given by$$P(f)(1)=f(1),\qquad P(f)(n+1)=f(n+1)+\sum_{i=1}^nP(f)(i).$$What is the coefficient of $f(m)$ in $P(f)(n)$ for $n\geq m$?

At first I got the impression that the coefficient is $1$ if $n=m, m+1$ and $2^{n-m-1}$ otherwise. However that seems to be an undercount since e.g. for the identity function we have $P(\mathrm{id})(n)=2^n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

> At first I got the impression that the coefficient is $1$ if $n=m, m+1$ and $2^{n-m-1}$ otherwise.

Yes, that's correct: $$\begin{eqnarray}
Pf(n+1) &=& f(n+1) + \sum_{i=1}^n Pf(i) \\
 &=& f(n+1) + Pf(n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Pf(i) \\
 &=& f(n+1) + 2Pf(n) - f(n) \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
from which the rest follows by induction.

I suspect that your confusion results from calculating check values of $P(x \to 1)$ thinking that you're calculating values of $P(\textrm{id}) = P(x \to x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider generating functions: $F(x) := \sum_{n\geq 1} f(n)x^n$ and $G(x) := \sum_{n\geq 1} P(f)(n)x^n$. Then the recurrence translates into
$$G(x) = F(x) + \frac{x}{1-x} G(x),$$
which implies $$G(x) = \frac{1-x}{1-2x}F(x).$$
Taking the coefficient of $x^n$ we get
$$P(f)(n) = f(n) + \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} 2^{n-m-1}\cdot f(m) .$$
That is, the coefficient of $f(m)$ in $P(f)(n)$ equals
$2^{n-m-1}$ when $m<n$, or $1$ when $m=n$.